# @types/node not recognised anymore after PnP loader mjs install

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v3

I have recently discovered **Yarn 3** and so far I was quite happy with the PnP features. Since I mainly work with **monorepos**, I wanted to make use of **Yarn workspaces**. Unfortunately, I cannot get basic things to work. I have set up a test project to highlight the problem.

##### Setup & Configuration

**[1]** The project has the following structure

```
monorepo/
  .env
  - frontend/
    - app/
      - src/
  - tools/
    - scripts/
      - src/
         - script.ts
```

**[2]** I then initialise the project by running

```
yarn set version berry
yarn init
```

**[3]** followed by installing the basic packages to get my script running

```
yarn add -D typescript ts-node @types/node dotenv
yarn plugin import typescript
```

I have also initialised the scripts package in the `scripts/` folder, running `yarn init`.

**[4]** I then added my workspaces to the freshly created `package.json`

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.22",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "frontend/*",
    "tools/*"
  ],
}
```

**[4]** I run

```
yarn install
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
```

to create the workspace and install the **VSCode** SDK to get Typescript support for my IDE.

So far so good, I can print the workspace list and everything seems to be set up right. In my `script.ts` file however, I want to read a constant from the `.env` file

```js
// script.ts

import "dotenv/config";

const script = () => {
  const getEnv = process.env.SCRIPT;
  console.log(getEnv);
};

script();
```

and I can run

```
yarn ts-node tools/scripts/script.ts

>> Hello script
```

without problem.

##### The problem

Since I need the package `@graphql-codegen/cli` later on as a dependency I have installed this via

```
yarn workspace scripts add @graphql-codegen/cli
```

which adds a `.pnp.loader.mjs` to the root folder. This is not a problem as long as I don't have a `tsconfig.json` inside the `scripts/` folder! Once I do that I get the error

```
Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.
```

in the `script.ts` file. If I add `"types": ["node"]` to the compiler options in the tsconfig, I get

```
Can't get definition file for 'node'.
```

I have looked at several posts but I cannot get this working. Why in the first place `.pnp.loader.mjs` gets installed? It seems like it's still experimental (considering the Yarn output:

```
ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
```

This is driving me crazy, any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, seems like I've solved this issue

I'm still not sure what exactly happens with `.pnp.loader.mjs` and what it does exactly. I also don't know why the package `@graphql-codegen/cli` forces the **PnP Loader** to install but it seems that it somehow can't deal with workspaces. I simply had to add `@types/node` to the dependencies in the `scripts` package by

```
yarn workspace scripts add @types/node
```

then having my `tsconfig.json` for the `scripts` package like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

##### Update

It seems like you can also skip the `"types": ["node"]` in your `tsconfig`.